# Display only one error message per field with JSR 303

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have multiple validation annotation on each filed of my bean, but I want to display only first failed message for each field in my spring MVC application where I am using JSR 303. Currently, it is evaluating all the constraints and displaying all the messages messages for each field. When a filed is empty, I dont want to evaluate its min and max constraint.

I have tried with groups, but it is not working as expected and more over I need to invoke the validator explicitly  something like validator.validate() which I want to avoid.

IS there any alternative to achieve this by over writing some validation classes?

I have at least 3 constraints for each field and maximum 5. Displaying all theses messages for each field is not at all looking good. I am suing spring 4.x and hibernate 4.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is via groups and group sequences. That's the only portable feature which ensures an validation order and termination of validation if a constraint within a group fails. Can you not assign the constraints in your bean to appropriate groups and then redefine the default groups sequence for the bean itself? See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-default-group-class

Comment: Groups are not working as expected, in my case. Moreover I need to call the validator explicitly by passing these groups.

Comment: What is happening with groups is that...lets say I have two form bean variables as name and email, then I have constraints as "@NotEmpty" for both the variables and additionally "@Email" for email variable. Now if I dont enter anything on the name field and wrong email format for email field then I should get error message as "This field is required" for name field and "Invalid email" error message for email field. But with groups, it is just displaying error message only for name field and nothing for email field. As only first group fields are validated.

Comment: You are right your specific use case is currently not supported. See also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-462 and https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-248. So there is a cumbersome work around via groups and group sequences. See the mentioend HV issue.

Comment: I have gone back to basic spring validator and wrote my own if else conditions to check each validation only if is succeeded the previous constraint. This way I have got whatever behavior I wanted. But I wonder why JSR 303 is not that flexible in achieving this. It is very basic requirement in validations.

Comment: @user1614862, i have the same error, how did you fix it ?